# Android studio gradle sync failing everytime

Tags: android-studio

I have downloaded android studio But when I start it always there is some kind of error when Gradle is syncing I really need help I have searched on youtube and google but I couldn't fix it but now I'm trying on StackOverflow if I can find out how to fix it

It is giving an error called:-

> Invalid injection android support version '202.7660.26.42.7351085',
> expected to be of the form 'w.x.y.z'

Plzz help

Comment: What operating system do you use? Maybe you should reinstall Gradle on your local machine.

Comment: I use windows 10 operating system and I have already reinstalled gradle

Answer (score 0):

As we can see from YouTrack it's an Android studio error

Here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-268774

JetBrains developers gave a reference to solution:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187470273?pli=1

Hope this helps you. If not - I suggest that you reinstall Gradle to a newer version.